# Basic Matplotlib Scatter Plot From Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pandas

How to make a basic scatter plot of column in a DataFrame vs the index of that DataFrame? Im using python 2.7.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataframe['Col'].plot()
plt.show()
```

This shows a line chart of 'Col' plotted against the values in my DataFrame index (dates in this case).

But how do I plot a scatterplot rather than a line chart?

I tried

```
plt.scatter(dataframe['Col'])
plt.show()
```

But `scatter()` requires 2 arguments. So how do I pass the series `dataframe['Col']` and my dataframe index into `scatter()` ?

I for this I tried

```
plt.scatter(dataframe.index.values, dataframe['Col'])
plt.show()
```

But chart is blank.

Comment: That works for me... can you include `dataframe.head()` and `dataframe.describe()` in your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strange. That ought to work.

Running this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Col': np.random.uniform(size=1000)})
plt.scatter(dataframe.index, dataframe['Col'])
```

spits out something like this

[image]

Maybe `quit()` and fire up a new session?

Comment: How are you getting that color theme? When I'm executing the same commands, it looks like the regular old and boring matplotlib type of chart.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to change from lines to points (and not really want/need  to use matplotlib.scatter) you can simply set the style:

```
In [6]: df=  pd.DataFrame({'Col': np.random.uniform(size=1000)})

In [7]: df['Col'].plot(style='.')
Out[7]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x4c3bb10>
```

[image: scatter_example]

See the docs of [DataFrame.plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) and the general [plotting documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

Comment: How are you getting that color theme? When I'm executing the same commands, it looks like the regular old and boring matplotlib type of chart.

Comment: Just use `pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'` before you plot or use your own [`matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)